# R Markdown slides with reveal.js: How to left align list items (bullets and numbers)?

Tags: css, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

How can I **align the list items at the left page margin of the slide**?

It seems that `revealjs` is always using the longest list item text, centers it at the slide then left aligns all other list items under this one:

```
---
title:
output: 
        revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

## list items
* a
* picture
* says more
* than a thousand words

or

1. item 1
1. item 2
```

I have tried to embed a CSS style sheet after the slide header, but
it has no impact:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .reveal li {
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
```

PS: I am using RStudio with the `revealjs` package.

Answer (score 15):

I have found the solution.

For a consistent layout I left align not only the unordered and ordered list items but also text paragraphs using the following embedded style:

```
---
title:
output: 
        revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

## list items

<style type="text/css">
  .reveal p {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .reveal ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .reveal ol {
    display: block;
  }  
</style>

* a
* picture
* says more
* than a thousand words

or

1. item 1
1. item 2
```

Sources:

1. You can browse the list of styles that revealjs defines to find out the active property values:

   https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/theme/template/theme.scss
2. Examine the semantics of the different property values to find your desired layout, e. g. for the `display` property:

   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp